# Insert spaces that will get deleted automatically

Tags: vim, indentation

I use the following code to make `cc` preserve the existing indentation when the line is not empty, and to use the calculated indentation (using `indentexpr`) when the line is empty.

```
function SmartCC()
  if getline('.') !~# '\S'
    return 'cc'
  else
    let spaces = repeat(' ', indent('.'))
    return '0d$i' . spaces
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> cc SmartCC()
```

The only problem I have with it is that, unlike the built-in `cc`, this inserts "real" spaces and not "tentative" spaces that get deleted automatically if nothing is typed on that line.

Is there a way to insert such tentative spaces?

Or maybe what I'm trying to achieve is already available by setting some secret option?

To make it clear, a plugin that removes *all* trailing spaces is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following hack:

```
function SmartCC_IndentExpr(indent, savedindentexpr)
    let &l:indentexpr=a:savedindentexpr
    return a:indent
endfunction
function SmartCC()
    if getline('.')=~#'\S'
        let &l:indentexpr='SmartCC_IndentExpr('.indent('.').', '.string(&l:indentexpr).')'
    endif
    return 'cc'
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> cc SmartCC()
```

. The idea is to set `&l:indentexpr` only for the period of evaluation `cc`. As it is known that `cc` checks indent only once and nothing triggers the check before `cc` under such circumstances then the `&l:indentexpr` itself can be used to restore `&l:indentexpr` back before indent is checked for the second time for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

`cc` is already smart enough to preserve the indentation of the current line. Do you have `autoindent` on?

Comment: `cc` is too smart — it uses `indentexpr` to calculate the indentation. The calculated indentation does not necessarily coincide with the existing one.

Comment: What indentation settings do you have? Wouldn't `^c$` do what you want (leaving the current indentation and changing whatever comes after)?

Comment: `^c$` is a better way to do what I already have, but it doesn't delete "unused" indentation, either. Which indentation settings do you want to know?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what you want to do. You want `cc` to respect indentation when there's text on the line and not respect it when there's only whitespace putting you in insert mode at column 1. Is that correct? Is that correct?

Comment: No. In both cases I want to get some indentation. In both cases I want that indentation to be deleted when it's "unused". But if there's some text on the line, I want indentation to be preserved. If there's no text on the line, I want the indentation to be determined by `indentexpr` (that's what I get from the standard `cc` by default).

Comment: What are your indentation settings? All of them.

Comment: `indentexpr` is set to a fairly complex function. `autoindent` is on. `indentkeys=!^F,o,O`.

Comment: Try `:set ci et st`. Here, `cc` always respects indentation, even if it's a mix of spaces and tabs.

Comment: What made you think that tabs are a problem here? I use only spaces, and I have `expandtab` set. `st` is some Amiga option, I don't believe it's somehow relevant.

Comment: I meant `sta`, sorry. Anyway, it seems that I don't understand what you want to achieve. At all.

Comment: @romainl I guess I got it and can explain by an example: on line `__a` (`_` is space, `a` is arbitrary text starting with non-whitespace character) `cc` should turn it into `__#` (`#` is cursor) and then to empty after escape. Additional problem: `==` on the line turns it into `____a` hence unmodified `cc` will turn it into `____#`, not `__#`. If `a` is absent existing behavior of `cc` should be kept.

Comment: I would suggest that fixing your indentation settings so that the calculated indent is correct.  Maybe that would solve your problem without requiring workarounds.  (I generally feel that patches to work around bugs are a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to on-demand space stripping but I have this to delete trailing spaces on save, maybe that's enough for you?

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.{c,cpp,h}  %s/\s\+$//e
```